# Meteor/Node: How to Inspect function

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am trying to use a node module with no documentation.

Given this situation, I would like to be able to inspect the function just like if I were on the client side and used the code `console.log(functionName);`
The browser will output the functionName with the parameters and through this I can confirm how many arguments are required to be passed in the function...
 and if I click on that line it will lead me to the block of code for that function where I can do further analysis...

What is a way to achieve this or achieve this similarly on the server side with in Meteor JS or Node JS???